# Drawing text in vertices using polygon regular tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying plot the regular polygon induced by the equation `x^(11)+1=0`. I've drawn the polygon and the circunference with this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\draw [very thick,<->] (-1.5,0)--(1.5,0);
\draw [very thick,<->] (0,-1.5)--(0,1.5);
\draw[thick,red!90!black] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\node [draw, thick, blue!90!black,rotate=90,minimum size=6cm,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=11] at (0,0) {};    

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now, I want to add the text `w_i` to the i-th vertex. How can I do it?

Comment: Time to call `\foreach` I guess.

Comment: [This answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136450/19356) was written to help you.

Comment: Mmmm... that would be very boring, Doesn't exist an option using regular polygon to refer explicitly to vertices of a regular polygon? I've read the official TIKZ in regular polygon section but it cannot put any reference about this.

Comment: @Tobal Where is the `w_1` located and what direction do `w_2, w_3, etc` go?

Comment: w_1 is the first vertex of the polygon, the exactly position is very difficult to know, but it must be located in (cos(pi/11),sin(pi/11)) and so on. But with Polygon Regular tikz option i don't use this Euler formula because I only plot a regular polygon centered in (0,0) with 11 sides and then i've rotated 90 degrees, this is the phase angle. I've written that I've drawn the regular polygon of all solutions of x^11+1=0 equation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Updated**

I've decided to update my answer by adding a counter to the `foreach` statement. This way it is much more automatized and the code is shorter.

The `foreach` adds the nodes at each corner of the polygon, which can be referred to using `corner #` (you can find this in the [Tikz Manual](http://paws.wcu.edu/tsfoguel/tikzpgfmanual.pdf), page 229), but it starts the subscript number from 0 at a certain corner and adds 1 to the previous value.

Anyway, here it is:

[image: graph image]

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\draw [very thick,<->] (-1.5,0)--(1.5,0);
\draw [very thick,<->] (0,-1.5)--(0,1.5);
\draw[thick,red!90!black] (0,0) circle (1cm);

\node (pol) [draw, thick, blue!90!black,rotate=90,minimum size=6cm,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=11] at (0,0) {}; 

\foreach \n [count=\nu from 0, remember=\n as \lastn, evaluate={\nu+\lastn}] in {7,8,...,10,11,1,2,...,5,6} 
\node[anchor=\n*(360/11)]at(pol.corner \n){$\omega_{\nu}$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `w_{10}` and `w_{11}`.

Comment: @Marienplatz Thank you! Why was it behaving like that?

Comment: Because of the need of grouping. :-)

Comment: Thanks! Thanks! This is exactly i would wish it. Many many thanks!!

Comment: `\omega_1` must be on `(1;16.36^\circ)` which is in the first quadrant.

Comment: I think your code can still be simplified to reduce many more keystrokes.

Comment: @Marienplatz Are you thinking about a `\foreach` that applies labels automatically by using a counter? Or something else? :D

Comment: In this case, acceptable results can be obtained by  using `\foreach\n in{1,...,11}\node[anchor=\n*(360/11)]at(pol.corner \n){$\omega_{\n}$};`

Comment: @MarkWibrow That's cool. I still need to master the `foreach` function, it has great potential. :D

Comment: @Tobal I've updated my answer with a slightly better solution (still using the foreach but with a counter) and I fixed the labels. :)

Comment: @Marienplatz I fixed the labels (and improved the code). :D

Comment: @MarkWibrow I've taken your suggestion but changed it to print the labels where they needed to be. :D

Answer (score 6):

The correct solution (from mathematics point of view) with PSTricks. I used zero-based index here (because the OP wants it).

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}

\makeatletter

\def\Atom#1{%
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none,linecolor=lightgray!50](0,0)(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \pscircle[dimen=m,linecolor=lightgray]{2}
    \degrees[#1]
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=\numexpr#1+1]{0}{#1}{2 t .5 add \pst@angleunit PtoC}{P}  
    \psnline[linecolor=blue](0,\Pnodecount){P}
    \multido{\i@=0+1}{\Pnodecount}{\qdisk(P\i@){2pt}\uput{2.2}[(P\i@)](0,0){$\omega_{#1}^{\i@}$}}
\end{pspicture}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \multido{\i=1+1}{12}{\Atom{\i}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### A bonus puzzle

Why did I add `.5` to  `t` in `2 t .5 add \pst@angleunit PtoC`? :-)

### Latest edit

Another method that seems to be more complicated but it is still fun!

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl,pst-plot}

\psset{CurveType=polygon}

\makeatletter
\def\Atom#1{%
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-3,-3)(3,3)
  \psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none,linecolor=lightgray!50](0,0)(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \pscircle[linecolor=red]{2}
    \degrees[#1]
    \def\points{}\def\names{}\def\angles{}
    \multido{\i@=0+1,\n@=.5+1.0}{#1}
    {
        \xdef\points{\points(!2 \n@\space \pst@angleunit PtoC){A\i@}}
        \xdef\names{\names \omega_{\i@},}
        \xdef\angles{\angles \n@,}
    }
    \edef\args{[PointName={\names},PosAngle={\angles}]\points}
    \expandafter\pstGeonode\args
\end{pspicture}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\multido{\i=1+1}{12}{\Atom{\i}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only for more clearly I've rearrenged the order of vertices in the correct mathematical order:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, calc}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\draw [very thick,<->] (-1.5,0)--(1.5,0);
\draw [very thick,<->] (0,-1.5)--(0,1.5);
\draw[thick,red!90!black] (0,0) circle (1cm);

\node (pol) [draw, thick, blue!90!black,rotate=90,minimum size=6cm,regular polygon, regular polygon sides=11] at (0,0) {}; 

\foreach \anchor/\label/\placement in
    {corner 1/$w_5$/above left, 
     corner 2/$w_6$/left, 
     corner 3/$w_7$/left, 
     corner 4/$w_8$/below,
     corner 5/$w_9$/below,   
     corner 6/$w_{10}$/right,
     corner 7/$w_0$/right,
     corner 8/$w_1$/above,
     corner 9/$w_2$/above,
     corner 10/$w_3$/above,
     corner 11/$w_4$/above}
\draw[shift=(pol.\anchor)] plot coordinates{(0,0)}
node[font=\scriptsize,\placement] {\label};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: regular polygon of 11-th unity-roots with math label order fixed]

Comment: Do you want to use zero-based index?

Comment: Yep! In my own latex document (a pdf book) it has got the right meanning, because I'm using the Euler formula to explain how to calculate the unity's nth-roots

Comment: @Tobal Want me to update the answer? I realize that the position of the labels is not correct. :D

Comment: I don't understand you very well, can you explain more, please? The order of the labels is the correct, the position? please type the code cuz it's very difficult to me understand you, i don't speak english ;-)

Comment: See my answer, the position of the root in my answer is correct.

Comment: Please, rewrite the code because i suspect you are talking about put the labels in the exactly, exactly place. I know the polygon is correct, or not? Well the polygon is correct

Comment: ok, i understand now, tomorrow i'll calculate all the points with octave and i'll fix the problem with the labels, now it's very late in Spain to do that. Thanks!!!

Comment: @Marienplatz , I've already fixed the label order in math way ordering. Your PSTRICKS code is very cool!!! Thanks everybody for your help !!!!

Comment: You can shorten you loop quite a bit: try `\foreach \x in {1,...,11}
{ \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\l}{mod(\x+4,11)}
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\d}{360/11*(\x-1)+170}
 \draw[shift=(pol.corner \x)] plot coordinates{(0,0)} node[font=\scriptsize,label=\d: $\omega_{\l}$] {};
}`