# Draw Vertices of Regular Polygon

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pstricks, asymptote

I am trying to draw just the nodes (no sides) at the vertices of a regular hexagon. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141690/7489) should be easily modified to accomplish what I want, but I am such a novice that I have difficulty understanding the example. Ideally, each vertex would be a separate *named* node so that I can easily draw edges between them (I will be making several different graphs using these same nodes).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the `regular polygon` shape from the `shapes.geometric` library, setting `draw=none`. Giving the node the name `a`, the vertices will be named `a.corner 1`, `a.corner 2` etc.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% create the node
\node[draw=none,minimum size=2cm,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6] (a) {};

% draw a black dot in each vertex
\foreach \x in {1,2,...,6}
  \fill (a.corner \x) circle[radius=2pt];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I want to draw a regular plolygons with label at vertices. How I  can do?

Comment: @minthao_2011 Place nodes at `a.corner 1` etc. See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141668/drawing-text-in-vertices-using-polygon-regular-tikz

Answer (score 10):

Time to call `\foreach`. Of course, it is possible to use a lot of other tools.

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \a in {0,60,...,300} { %\a is the angle variable
\draw[fill] (\a:2cm) circle (1pt); % 2cm is the radius; 1pt is the radius of the small bullet
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here are some other possible options, if you want to change colors.

```
\draw[line width=.7pt,blue,fill=yellow] (\a:1.5cm) circle (2pt);
```

[image]

Comment: I like the simplicity of your code, but is there a way to modify it so that I have names for each of the created nodes?

Answer (score 8):

Here is a PSTricks solution (with some extra features -- just remove the code not needed or outcomment it):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{
  pst-poly,
  pstricks-add
}
\usepackage[
%  locale = DE,
  round-mode = places,
  round-precision = 2
]{siunitx}
\usepackage{xfp}

% calculations
\newcommand*\Angle{\fpeval{360/\sides}}
\newcommand*\sidelength{\fpeval{2*\radius*sin(pi/\sides)}}
\newcommand*\radiusI{\fpeval{\radius*cos(pi/\sides)}}
%\newcommand*\areaI{\fpeval{pi*\radiusI^2}}
%\newcommand*\areaC{\fpeval{pi*\radius^2}}
%\newcommand*\areaRatio{\fpeval{cos(pi/\sides)^2}}

\psset{dimen = m}

\begin{document}

% constants
\def\sides{6}
\def\radius{3.5}

\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture}(-\radius,-\radius)(\radius,\radius)
  % centre
  \pnode(0,0){C}
  % regular polygon with dots at corners
  \rput(C){%
    \PstPolygon[
      PolyNbSides = \sides,
      unit = \radius
    ]
  }
 {\psset{linestyle = dashed}
  % inscribed circle
  \pscircle(C){\radiusI}
  % circumscribed circle
  \pscircle(C){\radius}}
  % dots with labels at the corners and lines from the centre to the corners
  \multido{\r = 0+\Angle, \i = 1+1}{\sides}{
    \psRelLine[
      angle = \r,
      linestyle = dotted
    ](C)(\radius,0){1}{A}
    \psdot[
      linecolor = red
    ](\radius;\r)
    \uput[\r](\radius;\r){$P_{\i}$}
  }
  % dot at centre
  \psdot[
    linecolor = blue!60
  ](C)
  % label position
  \pcline[
    linestyle = none,
    offset = 9pt
  ](C)(\radius,0)
  % label
  \ncput{$r = \num[round-mode = off]{\radius}$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}

\bigskip

\noindent
Regular $\sides$-gon with side length~$s = \num{\sidelength}$.

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: `\psdot(\radius;\rA)`

Comment: Arrrh, yes. Thank you. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: you can also do `\degrees[\sides]` and then simply `\multido{\iA=0+1}{\sides}{...}`

Answer (score 6):

Since someone added an [asymptote](/questions/tagged/asymptote) tag, I'll go ahead and give an Asymptote solution. Note that the programming abilities of Asymptote have the following advantages:

1. You can store all the points in an array, which makes it easy to reference them.
2. It is easy and natural to create points for future reference without drawing them, if so desired.

The solution (with comments):

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
size(3cm,0);    // scale the final picture to be 3cm wide
pair[] vertices;    // an empty array of points
int n = 11;    // number of sides
real r = 1.0;    // radius of the circle in which the polygon is inscribed
// Add the vertices to the array:
for (real angle = 0; angle < 360; angle += 360/n) {
    // The `push` command adds its argument to the end of the array.
    vertices.push(r*dir(angle));  // r*dir(angle) gives the point with polar coordinates (r, angle).
}
// Draw the vertices:
for (pair vertex : vertices)
    dot(vertex);

// Draw a couple lines in respective colors:
draw(vertices[0] -- vertices[6], red);
draw(vertices[1] -- vertices[9], blue);
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Feel free to always add Asymptote solution to any questions related to plotting, drawing, diagramming, etc because it is allowed by law in this site.

Answer (score 5):

A recommended solution with PSTricks. Note that `n`-side polygon needs `n+1` for the `plotpoints`.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=13]{0}{360}{2 t PtoC}{A}
    \psnline[linestyle=none,showpoints](0,\Anodecount){A}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Note

`\curvepnodes` (implemented in `pst-node`) needs `plotpoints` (implemented in `pst-plot`). It seems to be a bit weird as IMHO, `pst-node` implementing `\curvepnodes` should load `pst-plot` internally to make `plotpoints` available.

### Miscellaneous

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=24pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}
\psset{saveNodeCoors}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=13]{0}{360}{2 t PtoC}{A}
    \psnline[showpoints](0,\Anodecount){A}
    \multido{\i=0+1}{\Anodecount}{\uput[!N-A\i.y N-A\i.x atan](A\i){$A_{\i}$}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For labels, you could try something like this based on the answer from Torbjørn T.:

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}   
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \a/\text in {0/A,60/B,120/C,180/D,240/E,300/F} 
    \draw[fill] (\a:2cm) circle (1pt) node[right] () {\text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces this

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I use `tkz-euclide` with code

```
\documentclass[border=1.5mm,12pt]{standalone}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide,amsmath} 
\usetkzobj{all} 
\tikzset{hidden/.style = {thick, dashed}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}\tkzDefPoint(2,0){A}
\tkzDefPointsBy[rotation=center O angle 360/6](A,B,C,D,E){B,C,D,E,F}
\tkzDrawPoints[fill =black,size=10,color=black](A,B,C,D,E,F)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](B,C)
\tkzLabelPoints[right](A)
\tkzLabelPoints[left](D)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](E,F)
\tkzDrawPolygon[ultra thick](A,B,C,D,E,F)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]