# Drawing diagonals of a hexagon with asymptote

Tags: diagrams, asymptote

So I wanted to make a hexagon with the diagonals marked in Asymptote but I couldn't figure out how to do it, so can someone please help write the Asymptote code for me? I'm very new to Asymptote so I have no idea how to do it.

I attached an image of what I'm trying to make.
[image]
Thank you! :D

Comment: Why are you even doing this in asymptote when you can draw it directly in tikz

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152191/draw-vertices-of-regular-polygon

Comment: @daleif: In some cases Ti*k*Z has a clear advantage over Asymptote. This is not one of those cases. So we should not assume that preferring Asymptote here requires justification. (That having been said, anyone who wants to give a Ti*k*Z answer is welcome to do so, in accordance with TeX.SX practices.)

Comment: @CharlesStraats then please explain why asymptote is the best tool here.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please modify the title of your question with a clear title that allows you to understand what it is about and allows it to be indexed by search engines. such as `Drawing diagonals of a hexagon with asymptote`.

Comment: @daleif I'm sorry I was not clear. Neither tool has a clear advantage over the other for this particular problem. The way I understand your comment, you see Ti*k*Z as the default solution for creating diagrams and Asymptote as something only to be used in special cases. That policy may well be optimal for your usage pattern. But you should not treat it as universal. There are any number of valid reasons the OP might prefer to invest in learning Asymptote rather than Ti*k*Z, and they are not obligated to share them with us.

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways to code it in `Asymptote`. here is one, file `hexa.asy`:

```
// run 
//   asy hexa.asy
// to get hexa.pdf
// 
settings.outformat="pdf";
size(4cm);
int n=6;
pair[] V= sequence(new pair(int i){return dir(360*i/n);}, n);
V.cyclic=true;
for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
  draw(V[i]--V[i+1]--V[i-1]--cycle,darkblue+0.7bp);
}
dot(V,UnFill);
```

[image]