# Draw a decagon in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-node, tikz-graphdrawing

I need to draw a graph with 10 nodes in LaTeX. I thought about doing it with tikz and try to give exact coordinates to draw a decagon but I don't know what coordinates to give.

Comment: `\begin{tikzpicture} \node[draw,minimum size=1cm,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=10] (a) {}; \end{tikzpicture}`?

Comment: Oh, you need `\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}` in your preamble.

Comment: Welcome to the TEX.SE. Do this link could be to help for you? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152191/draw-vertices-of-regular-polygon

Answer (score 2):

In this [link](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/regular-polygons/) you can find a series of regular polygons...I have changed the code to  have the penthagon. Here the drawing is without coordinates.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
% Radius of regular polygons
\newdimen\R
\R=1cm
This is a pentagon $n=10$, 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[yshift=-6.0\R] (0:\R) \foreach \x in {36,72,...,359} {
            -- (\x:\R)
        } -- cycle (90:\R) node[above] {$\scriptstyle n=10$} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
that it could be used as a symbol. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A solution with PSTricks only for either fun or comparison purposes.

`curvepnodes` is useful to define an array of nodes for any given number of nodes and curve functions. For example, we can use it to make an array of 12 nodes on a circle. `Offset` is provided as the rotation offset.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showpoints,dotscale=1](-4,-4)(4,4)
    \pstVerb{/Offset 30 def}%
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=11]{0}{360}{3 t Offset add PtoC}{A}
    \psnpolygon[linecolor=red](0,\numexpr\Anodecount-1){A}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Animated version

```
\documentclass[pstricks,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\multido{\i=0+10}{10}{%
\begin{pspicture}[showpoints,dotscale=6](-4,-4)(4,4)
    \pstVerb{/Offset \i\space def}%
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=13]{0}{360}{3 t Offset add PtoC}{A}
    \psnpolygon[linecolor=red](0,\numexpr\Anodecount-1){A}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice the animation and your code.

Comment: @Sebastiano: Thank you. Italian grapes are delicious. :-)

Comment:  aahahahah.