# Regular polygon: edges between vertices of odd index

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a regular polygon in which there is an edge between the consecutive vertices of odd index: For instance with 8 vertices, I want a path `1 -- 3 -- 5 -- 7 -- 1`. To do this with a large number of vertices, I'd like to do this automatically rather than to handwrite the full path.

Using some answers here (in particular [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141678/7269)), I've come up with the following solution (here with 16 vertices):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (pol) [minimum size=\textwidth,regular polygon, rotate=90,regular polygon sides=8] at (0,0) {}; 
\foreach \n in {1, 2, ..., 8} {
    \node[anchor=\n*(360/8)] at (pol.corner \n) {\n};
}
\foreach \n [remember=\n as \lastn (initially 7)] in {1, 3, ...,  7} {
    \path[draw] (pol.corner \lastn) -- (pol.corner \n);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that I get the path `3 -- 5 -- 7 -- 1` plus the edge `3 -- 7` instead of the path I wanted. It seems to me (I may well be wrong!) that `\lastn` is not correctly updated at the beginning of the loop.

**Do you see what is going wrong? Do you have a different way to achieve the same goal?**

Comment: Should `\lastn` be initialized to `7` instead of `8`? If I do that, I get exactly the shape that you describe at the beginning... path from `1--3--5--7--1`

Comment: Of course, this was a mistake! Yet, I still get the exact same path as I described, once the mistake corrected. I do not get the same shape as you seem to get! This reinforces my impression that `\lastn` is not correctly initialized in the `\foreach` loop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you can see here, there's no problem with your code and TiKZ 3.0

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (pol) [draw=red,minimum size=\textwidth,regular polygon, rotate=90,regular polygon sides=8] at (0,0) {}; 
\foreach \n in {1, 2, ..., 8} {
    \node[anchor=\n*(360/8)] at (pol.corner \n) {\n};
}
\foreach \n [remember=\n as \lastn (initially 7)] in {1, 3, ...,  7} {
    \path[draw] (pol.corner \lastn) -- (pol.corner \n);
}

\begin{scope}[yshift=13cm]
\node (pol) [draw=red,minimum size=\textwidth,regular polygon, rotate=90,regular polygon sides=18] at (0,0) {}; 
\foreach \n in {1, 2, ..., 18} {
    \node[anchor=\n*(360/18)] at (pol.corner \n) {\n};
}
\foreach \n [remember=\n as \lastn (initially 17)] in {1, 3, ...,  17} {
    \path[draw] (pol.corner \lastn) -- (pol.corner \n);
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Maybe an alternative for even-number-of-size polygons (odd is also possible but a little more tedious)?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\mycorner{18}
\node (pol) [minimum size=\textwidth,regular polygon, 
             rotate=90,regular polygon sides=\mycorner] at (0,0) {}; 
\foreach \n in {1, 2, ..., \mycorner} {
    \node[anchor=\n*(360/\mycorner)] at (pol.corner \n) {\n};
}
\foreach \n [evaluate={\modn = int(Mod(\n+2,\mycorner));}] in {1,3,...,\mycorner} {
    \path[draw] (pol.corner \n) -- (pol.corner \modn);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this nice solution! I'll accept your answer if nobody catches the problem in my solution...

Comment: @Bruno I suspect that you are using TikZ 2.10 and the problem will go away if you instead use `{1,3,5,7}` in your foreach loop. That was a known problem. Now it's v3.00 and it is solved. Alternatively you can try removing `(initially 7)` part and use `\def\lastn{7}` outside your loop manually.

Answer (score 6):

Done with MetaPost, inserted in a LuaLaTeX program. In the following code the `odd_subpolygon` takes care of all the job, with two parameters to be adjusted at will: the number `n` of sides of the main regular polygon and its radius `r` (in centimeters). As examples, the following code applies this macro thrice, respectively with `n=6`, `n=8` and `n=16`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
  \mplibsetformat{metafun}
  \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
  \everymplib{verbatimtex \leavevmode etex;
    % Macro producing a unit regular polygon
    vardef unit_regpoly(expr n) =
      save angl; angl := 360/n; right for i = 1 upto n-1: -- dir(i*angl) endfor -- cycle
    enddef;
    % Macro drawing a n-sided regular polygon of radius r and its subpolygon
    vardef odd_subpolygon(expr n, r) =
      clearxy; save polygon; path polygon; 
      polygon = unit_regpoly(n) scaled r; draw polygon withcolor red;
      % polygon and labels
      for i = 1 upto n: 
        z[i] = point i-1 of polygon; freelabel(decimal i, z[i], origin);
      endfor;
      % Subpolygon
      draw z1 for i = 3 step 2 until n: -- z[i] endfor -- cycle;
    enddef;
    r = 2cm; % radius parameter
    beginfig(0);}
  \everyendmplib{endfig;}
\begin{document} % Three examples, with n = 5, 8 and 16 respectively
\begin{center}
  \begin{mplibcode} odd_subpolygon(6, r); \end{mplibcode}
  \qquad
  \begin{mplibcode} odd_subpolygon(8, r); \end{mplibcode}
  \par\bigskip
  \begin{mplibcode} odd_subpolygon(16, r); \end{mplibcode}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A PSTricks solution using the [`pst-poly`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-poly) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{pst-poly}
\usepackage{xfp}

\newcommand*\hori[2]{\fpeval{#1+#2+0.05}}
\newcommand*\verti[2]{\fpeval{#1+#2+0.1}}

\def\polygon[#1]#2#3{%
\begin{pspicture}(-\hori{#1}{#2},-\verti{#1}{#2})(\hori{#1}{#2},\verti{#1}{#2})
  \rput(0,0){\PstPolygon[unit = #2, PolyNbSides = #3]}
  \rput(0,0){\PstPolygon[unit = #2, PolyNbSides = \fpeval{2*#3}, linecolor = red]}
  \multido{\i = 1+1}{\fpeval{2*#3}}{%
    \rput(\fpeval{(#1+#2)*cos(pi/#3*(\i-1))},\fpeval{(#1+#2)*sin(pi/#3*(\i-1))}){$\i$}}
\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}

\polygon[0.25]{2}{8}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The figure is drawn using the general marco

```
\polygon[distance between outer polygon and numbers]
        {<radius of the circumcircle>}
        {<number of sides of the inner polygon>}
```