# What's the difference between TikZ anchors and coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf

In his answer to [Accessing the logic values of a TikZ coordinate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18292/accessing-the-logic-values-of-a-tikz-coordinate), Jake proposes a code to get the value of TikZ coordinate.

Today I've tried to use it to answer [Make a polygon with automatically labelled nodes according to their coordinates](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179843/make-a-polygon-with-automatically-numbered-nodes-according-to-their-coordinates/179847#179847)
where I wanted to print coordinate values of some `node anchors`

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=5pt]{standalone}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\xcoord[2][center]{{%
    \pgfpointanchor{#2}{#1}%
    \pgfmathparse{\pgf@x/\pgf@xx}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
}}
\newcommand\ycoord[2][center]{{%
    \pgfpointanchor{#2}{#1}%
    \pgfmathparse{\pgf@y/\pgf@yy}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
}}
\makeatother

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=2}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, minimum size=2cm] (A) {A};
\node[above right] at (A.north east) {(\xcoord{A.north east},\ycoord{A.north east})};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but compilation stops with next error message

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named A.north east is known.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation. 
Type  H <return> for immediate help.  
...                                              
l.22 ... at (A.north east) {(\xcoord{A.north east}
                                 ,\ycoord{A.north east})};
```

Then I tried with a *real* `coordinate`

```
\coordinate (aux) at (A.north east);
\node[above right] at (A.north east) {(\xcoord{aux},\ycoord{aux})};
```

and it worked. Could you explain me why?

Comment: Probably `(A.north east)` has to be parsed char by char before finding which coordinate refers it to. This is done probably by tikz, and thus it cannot be done by `\pgfpointanchor`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at Jake's code, it has an optional argument, which by default is `center`, used in `\pgfpointanchor`. 
A quote from the manual:

> ```
> \pgfpointanchor{ node }{ anchor }
> ```
>
> This command is another “point command” like the commands described in Section 97. It returns the
>   coordinate of the given `anchor` in the given `node`.

So you should really use those macros as

```
\node[above right] at (A.north east) {(\xcoord[north east]{A}, ycoord[north east]{A})};
```

As you've used them, `\pgfpointanchor` looks for a node called `A.north east` but the name of the node is `A`.

The reason this works with a `coordinate` is that a `coordinate` is really a `node`.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=5pt]{standalone}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\xcoord[2][center]{{%
    \pgfpointanchor{#2}{#1}%
    \pgfmathparse{\pgf@x/\pgf@xx}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
}}
\newcommand\ycoord[2][center]{{%
    \pgfpointanchor{#2}{#1}%
    \pgfmathparse{\pgf@y/\pgf@yy}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
}}
\makeatother

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=2}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, minimum size=2cm] (A) {A};
\node[above right] at (A.north east) {(\xcoord[north east]{A},\ycoord[north east]{A})};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind using internal macros `\tikz@scan@one@point` will permit the use of TikZ coordinates. It will also take care of the default `center` anchor:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=5pt]{standalone}

\makeatletter
\def\xcoord#1{%
    % \tikz@scan@one@point takes an argument before the
    % coordinate which is the command to be executed after
    % the coordinate is parsed. \pgf@process just keeps
    % the coordinate calculation local and globally
    % sets \pgf@x and \pgf@y to the appropriate value.
    %
    % NB. Must use \nullfont to prevent naughty spaces.
    %
    {\nullfont\tikz@scan@one@point\pgf@process(#1)}%
    \pgfmathparse{\pgf@x/\pgf@xx}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
}
\def\ycoord#1{%
   {\nullfont\tikz@scan@one@point\pgf@process(#1)}%
   \pgfmathparse{\pgf@y/\pgf@yy}%
   \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
}
\makeatother

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=2}
\tikzset{mark cross at/.pic={
  \draw [red, shift={(#1)}, scale=1/20] (1,1) -- (-1,-1) (1,-1) -- (-1,1);
  \node [above=5pt,fill=blue!20, fill opacity=0.75, node font=\tiny\tt]
     at (#1) {(\xcoord{#1},\ycoord{#1})};
}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw, minimum size=4cm, outer sep=0pt] (A) {A};

\path (A) pic {mark cross at={A}}; 
\foreach \a in {north, south, east, west, north west, south west, south east, north east}
  \path pic {mark cross at={A.\a}}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]