# p evenly-spaced nodes on circle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to place p evenly-spaced nodes around a circle.

I want to draw the following picture with using document class [report].

[image]

*Edit:* What I have done so far,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,leqno,11pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,verbatim,amsmath,amsthm,latexsym,textcomp,amscd}
\usepackage{latexsym,amsfonts,amssymb,epsfig,verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,latexsym,graphics,textcomp}
%\usepackage[all,2cell,dvips]{xy}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \n {5}
\def \radius {1.5cm}
\def \margin {3}
\foreach \s in {1,...,\n} {%
   \node [anchor=center] at ({360/\n * (\s-1)}:\radius+ 1){$g^{\s}$};
   \filldraw[black] ({360/\n * (\s-1)}:\radius) circle (1pt) ;
   \node [anchor=center] at ({360/\n * (\s-1)}:\radius+0.3cm ){$g^{\s}$};
   \draw[>=latex] ({360/\n * (\s-1)+ \margin}:\radius)
      arc({360/\n * (\s-1)+\margin}:{360/\n * (\s)-\margin}:\radius);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a do-it-for-me question. Please show what you've got so far and then ask a specific question.

Comment: I just can draw a circle in tikz.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136357/drawing-a-regular-polygon-encompassed-by-a-circle, just don't draw the polygon.

Comment: Sorry sir. I can't do it by myself. Can you please  do it for me?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Perhaps this post might help you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145379/how-do-i-place-nodes-around-a-circle-in-tikz.

Answer (score 7):

This can be done in a single `\draw`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def \n {20}
        \def \radius {3}
        \draw circle(\radius)
              foreach\s in{1,...,\n}{
                  (-360/\n*\s:-\radius)circle(.4pt)circle(.8pt)circle(1.2pt)
                  node[anchor=-360/\n*\s]{$g^{\s}\ifnum\s=\n\relax=e\fi$}
              };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## ellipsis version

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def \n {20}
    \def \radius {3}
    \draw circle(\radius)(0:-\radius)circle(.4pt)circle(.8pt)circle(1.2pt)
          foreach\s in{0,...,7}{
              ({-360/\n*(\s-1)}:-\radius)circle(.4pt)circle(.8pt)circle(1.2pt)
              node[anchor={-360/\n*(\s-1)}]{$\ifcase\s\relax g^{p-1}=g^{-1}\or g^p=e\else g^{\pgfmathparse{int(\s-1)}\pgfmathresult}\fi$}
          }
          foreach\s in{9,...,\n}{
              ({-360/\n*(\s-2)}:-\radius)
              node[anchor={-360/\n*(\s-2)}]{$\cdot$}
          };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: You can probably replace `circle(.4pt)circle(.8pt)circle(1.2pt)` with `node[fill,circle, inner sep=1pt]{}`.